# Local video stream not showing when using Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, webrtc, android-camera2

Everything else in my app seems fine, both remote and local streams display just fine if I'm using `Camera1` API. But, when I try and use the `Camera2` API, the local video stream doesn't show anymore, a black screen shows instead. The local stream is still being displayed on the remote end though, and there's no error messages in the log either. The API is the only thing I changed in my code. Anyone knows what's going on here?

I came across a similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Pc-072DgjKg), but it's outdated and not testable as `setVideoHwAccelerationOptions()` has been depreciated and the related stuff is being handled by coded factories as described [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/SKSkOUHXB2A/uugaMVuJAgAJ).

Here's my code for building these factories, in case that's helpful:

```
final VideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory;
final VideoDecoderFactory decoderFactory;
encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
    rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */, false);
decoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Turns out all of the camera and rendering related stuff has to share a same `EglBase` instance and its `context`. I created multiple instances while initializing the connection.

As for the reason why local video stream doesn't show only when using `Camera2` API, I suppose is because `Camera2Enumerator` is the one that requires a context, likely `EglBaseContext`, whereas `Camera1` doesn't require it. (I'm not sure about this one, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Anyways, **TL;DR**: check the code and make sure you are using a **single `EglBase` instance** for all your related operations.